# Matching an array of Objects using Mockito

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I'm trying to set up a mock for a method that takes an array of Request objects:

```
client.batchCall(Request[])
```

I've tried these two variations:

```
when(clientMock.batchCall(any(Request[].class))).thenReturn(result);
...
verify(clientMock).batchCall(any(Request[].class));
```

and

```
when(clientMock.batchCall((Request[])anyObject())).thenReturn(result);
...
verify(clientMock).batchCall((Request[])anyObject());
```

But I can tell the mocks aren't being invoked.

They both result in the following error:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
clientMock.batchCall(
    <any>
);
-> at com.my.pkg.MyUnitTest.call_test(MyUnitTest.java:95)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
clientMock.batchCall(
    {Request id:123},
    {Request id:456}
);
```

Why does the  matcher not match the array? Is there a special matcher I need to use to match an array of objects? The closest thing I can find is AdditionalMatches.aryEq(), but that requires that I specify the exact contents of the array, which I'd rather not do.

Answer (score 12):

So I quickly put something together to see if I could find your issue, and can't below is my sample code using the any(Class) matcher and it worked. So there is something we are not seeing.

Test case

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ClientTest
{
    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        Client client = Mockito.mock(Client.class);

        Mockito.when(client.batchCall(Mockito.any(Request[].class))).thenReturn("");

        Request[] requests = {
            new Request(), new Request()};

        Assert.assertEquals("", client.batchCall(requests));
        Mockito.verify(client, Mockito.times(1)).batchCall(Mockito.any(Request[].class));
    }
}
```

client class

```
public class Client
{
    public String batchCall(Request[] args)
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Request Class

```
public class Request
{

}
```

Comment: Let the question's author to decide if it provides or not an answer to the question

Answer (score 6):

Necroposting, but check whether the method you're calling is declared as `batchCall(Request[] requests)` or `batchCall(Request... requests)`.

If it's the latter, try `when(clientMock.batchCall(Mockito.anyVararg()))`.

Comment: `Mockito.anyVararg()` is deprecated, use `(Type) Mockito.any()` instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the reason for me was, that the elements in the arrays had different orders.